# GeoFire and Firebase Error: Cannot convert value of type 'DatabaseReference' to expected argument type 'Firebase?'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I'm suddenly getting this error in Xcode:

> Cannot convert value of type 'DatabaseReference' to expected argument type 'Firebase?'

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users_location/")

let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: ref)
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Your code looks similar to this: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc#swift. I'm surprised about the `Firebase?` in the error message. What version of GeoFire are you using?

Comment: the Geofire version is 1.1.3

Answer (score 0):

You're using GeoFire [version 1.1.3](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc/releases#hd-5d10a52f), which is **ancient** (seriously: March 2016) and predates the introduction of the `DatabaseReference` class.

**I recommend upgrading to the [latest release](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc/releases) of GeoFire, which is 4.3.0 at the time of writing.**

Alternatively you could downgrade your version of the Realtime Database SDK to match that timeframe, but I'd recommend against that.